# Flutter:dialog pop earlier than loading data

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, dart, flutter

I have a list view with limited data and a full dialog box with full details which a user can change basically make a book request to network.As network call becomes asyn which results in pop out the dialog box earlier than changed data.
I am using Bloc Pattern and await for the network call.

```
   new FlatButton(
              child: new Text('BOOK', style: theme.textTheme.body1.copyWith(color: Colors.white)),
              onPressed: () {
                openShiftBloc.bookPressedSink.add(event.id);
                Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => Navigator.pop(context, DismissDialogAction.cancel));
               // Navigator.pop(context, DismissDialogAction.save);
              }
          )
```

Comment: On button press, you are triggering the `bookPressed` event and after 500ms, poping. It is not guaranteed, that network will finish in 500ms. Instead of poping in `buttonPress`, you have to listen to another stream which will give data from network.

Comment: Yeah i used a streambuilder but it didnot got listned here. And i had to listen to stream at the begining while building widget and the thing was working as Navigation was poping out after server response but problem arised as widget was building.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand. Can you provide some more code/details